# SQL query syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I got a syntax error on this query, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
UPDATE `jos_planning2_rosters` r
LEFT JOIN jos_planning2_rosters_setup s ON r.id = s.roster_id
LEFT JOIN jos_planning2_workplaces w ON s.workplace_id = w.id
WHERE r.roster_state =1
AND s.card_id IS NULL
AND s.type_id = '2'
AND r.roster_date >= DATE( NOW()) SET s.card_id = '1', s.type_id = '1' 
WHERE s.type_id = '2', s.card_id IS NULL, r.id = '8';
```

Comment: and we don't know what the error message is...

Comment: try replacing UPDATE `jos_planning2_rosters` with UPDATE 'jos_planning2_rosters' (` -> ')

Comment: Is this tsql? You can set an alias for the updated table. But without a conrete error message its just guessing

Comment: `Date(NOW())` should probably be `GetDate()` or `GetUTCDate()`, post the error. And you're missing a `from` and `set`.

Comment: @TheCodeKing: nope, those are *all* fine.

Comment: Please tag RDBMS. I've assumed MySQL from the back ticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do this, the query is a mess:

```
UPDATE s
SET    s.card_id = '1', 
       s.type_id = '1'
From   jos_planning2_rosters_setup s
       INNER JOIN jos_planning2_rosters r ON r.id = s.roster_id
WHERE  r.roster_state = 1
       AND s.card_id IS NULL
       AND s.type_id = '2'
       AND r.roster_date >= GetDate()
       AND r.id = '8';
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two `WHERE` clauses in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without those backticks around `jos_planning2_rosters`.

Comment: @Fabian, I think the OP is correct, you have two WHERE statements.  That is bad.

Comment: UPDATE `jos_planning2_rosters` r
  LEFT JOIN jos_planning2_rosters_setup s ON r.id = s.roster_id
  LEFT JOIN jos_planning2_workplaces w ON s.workplace_id = w.id
  SET s.card_id = '1', s.type_id = 1 WHERE
  s.type_id = 2, s.card_id IS NULL, r.id = '8'; this is my new query but still doesnt work

Comment: I think you have to have ANDs instead of commas between your WHERE statements.